# easiest possible plupload configuration and yet not working

Tags: javascript, plupload

I've just copied the [plupload getting started example](http://www.plupload.com/docs/Getting-Started) in a *.html file, and still can't have the browse feature working.

Clicking on 'browse' link doesn't do anything. 
The plupload.full.min.js is in the same directory and gets correctly loaded since if i take it out, i get an error.

The version of plupload library is the 2.1.2.

```
<head>

<script src="plupload.full.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
var uploader = new plupload.Uploader({
  browse_button: 'browse',
  url: 'www.google.com'
});

uploader.init();
</script>

</head>

<body>

<ul id="filelist"></ul>
<br />

<div id="container">
     <a id="browse">[Browse...]</a>
     <a id="start-upload">[Start Upload]</a>
</div>

</body>
```

Comment: you should use something like firebug to debug your javascript. if it doesn't load properly it won't work. check the path is correct, check syntax (i.e. do the browse_button: and url: need a comma between them?).  too many unknowns and not enough information to be able to help.

Comment: thanks, there was a comma, i deleted it by mistake when i removed a comment. the code is copied from the plupload site. i see no errors in the 'developers console' of chrome.

Comment: Looking at the example provided with the plupload 2.1.2 zip file it would appear that there is much more to it than the few lines you have included.  where did you get your example? this plupload dosen't seem nearly intuitive as one would wish..

Comment: I guess your javascript should come after your HTML (at least for the call to `init`). When you try to init your uploader, the DOM is not loaded yet.

Comment: @jbl, it is exactly as you pointed out. if you want to put it as an answer, i'm going to accept it. clearly it is not a plupload issue, but basic javascript one. on the other hand, as i said, this is the example in the plupload site, that should take into account this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said in the comments, the call to `uploader.init();` should be located below your html code
( Ideally, the call should be nested in a jquery `$(document).ready` event handler ).

If not, the uploader will try to init on a DOM which is not yet loaded, and will fail.

This handler could be located wherever you want, but still ideally below your html code (as for the rest of your javascript)

If you take a look at the full example [on the getting started page](http://www.plupload.com/docs/Getting-Started) you will notice 
that the javascript is located at the bottom of the body element. (I must confess that the tutorial is a little bit misleading)